# Did I understand correctly how to calculate the total derivative of a function?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, partial-derivative

I have to calculate the total derivative of a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) = |x-p|$ for each point where $f$ is differentiable, and where $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is fixed. I think I made it but since it's the first time I'm calculating a total derivative, I would be happy if someone could check what I did (sorry in advance for the english mistakes):

So, let's begin with some things we saw during our lecture, so that things are clear:

> - Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set and $ x_0 \in U$. A function $f: U \rightarrow R$ is called **Fréchet differentiable** at $x_0$ if there exists a linear map $L : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)-L(x-x_0)}{|x-x_0|} = 0 .$$
> - If $f$ is Fréchet differentiable, then $L$ is called the **total derivative of $f$ at $x_0$**. That map is unique and is noted by $ df(x_0) := L$.
> - If $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Fréchet differentiable at $x_0 \in U$, then $f$ is "partially differentiable" at $x_0$ and the map $L$ mentioned above satisfies, for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$:
>     $$L(v) = \left\langle \nabla f(x_0), v \right\rangle .$$

And here is what I did so far, considering the function I'm supposed to work with, that is: $f(x) = |x-p|$ for $x, p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $p$ being fixed:

If $n=1$, we know that $x=p$ is going to be a problem since $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $h(x) := |x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$. We're going to see that the same problem appears if $n > 1$, so $f$ is not differentiable at $x=p$.

Now, since $L(v) = \left\langle \nabla f(x_0), v \right\rangle \forall v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have:
$$L(v) = \left\langle \nabla f(x_0), v \right\rangle$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow L(v) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} v_i \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} (x_0)$$

We have as well:
$$f(x_0) = |x_0 - p| = \left| \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} p_1 \\ p_2 \\ \vdots \\ p_n\end{pmatrix} \right|$$
$$= \sqrt{(x_1 - p_1)^2 + (x_2 - p_2)^2 + ... + (x_n - p_n)^2}$$
$$= \left((x_1 - p_1)^2 + (x_2 - p_2)^2 + ... + (x_n - p_n)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$\Longrightarrow \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x_0) = \frac{1}{2} \left((x_1 - p_1)^2 + (x_2 - p_2)^2 + ... + (x_n - p_n)^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(x_i - p_i)^2$$
$$= \frac{1}{2} \left((x_1 - p_1)^2 + (x_2 - p_2)^2 + ... + (x_n - p_n)^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(x_{i}^2 -2p_ix_i + p_{i}^2)$$
$$= \frac{1}{2} \left((x_1 - p_1)^2 + (x_2 - p_2)^2 + ... + (x_n - p_n)^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot (2x_i - 2p_i)$$
$$= \left((x_1 - p_1)^2 + (x_2 - p_2)^2 + ... + (x_n - p_n)^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot (x_i - p_i)$$
$$= \frac{(x_i - p_i)}{\sqrt{\left((x_1 - p_1)^2 + (x_2 - p_2)^2 + ... + (x_n - p_n)^2\right)}}$$

Therefore,
$$L(v) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{v_i \cdot (x_i - p_i)}{\sqrt{\left((x_1 - p_1)^2 + (x_2 - p_2)^2 + ... + (x_n - p_n)^2\right)}}$$
$$= \frac{v_1 \cdot (x_1 - p_1) + v_2 \cdot (x_2 - p_2) + ... + v_n \cdot (x_n - p_n)}{\sqrt{\left((x_1 - p_1)^2 + (x_2 - p_2)^2 + ... + (x_n - p_n)^2\right)}},$$
which is the total derivative we where looking for. As mentioned above, we can see it would be problematic if $x=p$ since the numerator and denominator would be both equal to $0$.

...and, that's it. Does it make sense? Did I understand correctly how to calculate such things?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: Your calculations are ok, but at the end you should use the fact that if partial derivatives are continuous in a ngbh of a point then the map is differentiable at that point. [You could also make a direct proof avoiding partial derivatives]

Comment: @H.H.Rugh Ok, thanks for your answer! I'm new to all that stuff so I would never have thought of using the fact you mentioned... I'm going to study a little bit more then. Thanks again!